# Do wonders in puppeted cities have any effect?

Tags: civilization-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hostile takeovers: Does your civilization receive the benefits of wonders?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10756/hostile-takeovers-does-your-civilization-receive-the-benefits-of-wonders)

I just took over York from england and puppeted it. It has **The Forbidden Palace** (unhappiness in cities) and I was curious if I got its benefit.

Comment: It sounds like you're in a prime position to test this yourself: Make a save game, and make note of your current happiness/unhappiness and their mods. Annex york. Compare the new happiness values to the old one to see what changed. If the unhappiness from # of cities went down, puppet cities with wonders don't count for you. If the unhappiness remains the same (or more than likely, went up from having an annexed city) you were already benefiting from the wonder. Reload save game (if you'd rather not have annexed york).

Comment: Unfortunately, I was well beyond that point by the time I read this, however next time I take over a city with wonders, I may just test it myself to post an actual answer :)